# cudaFreeHost() invalid arguments error

Tags: c++, cuda, malloc, free

I am using `cudaMallocHost()` with `cudaFreeHost()` in a class. An example of my code:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

class myClass{
public:
    int* bitmap[5];
    void Malloc(){
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
            cudaMallocHost(&bitmap[i], sizeof(int)*10000);
            memset(bitmap[i], 0, sizeof(int)*10000);
        }
    }
    void Delete(){
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
            cudaFreeHost(bitmap[i]);
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    myClass mc;
    mc.Malloc();
    //copy 'bitmap[]' to gpu and call some kernel function
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    mc.Delete();
}
```

The above code return error invalid arguments (value 11) when calling `cudaFreeHost()`, `cudaFreeHost` returns no error.

I tried to change to array of pointer into different variable but the errors still occur. I even put the `cudaFreeHost()` right after `cudaMallocHost()` but there are still errors.

I verified that the error does not occur every time when I call `cudaFreeHost()`.

The `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` is added to ensure all the copy operations are done.

If I change all cudaHost opration into normal operation (i.e. new and delete), the program works fine.

I tried to change each variable in bitmap to b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 as following, but same error occurs.

```
cudaMallocHost(&b1, sizeof(int) * 10000);
cudaFreeHost(b1);
```

Comment: Can you provide your original code? the example you provide is not legal C++

Comment: try `int *bitmap[5];` instead of `int bitmap[5];`

Comment: @willkill07 sorry for the sloppy code. I edited it and it should be legal C++ now

Comment: @RobertCrovella, sorry that was typo.

Comment: Please provide a complete code that someone else can compile without having to add anything or change anything.  For example, I don't know what `size` is.  Please don't just tell me what `size` is.  Please provide a **complete** code.  Such as a [mcve].  If you're not sure about it, copy the code you have posted, put it into a new empty project without adding anything else, and try to compile it.  When you get it to compile, then provide that code here.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, the above code is executable now. However, the above code runs without problem. But in my code the problem still exists. I wonder why C++ operations new and delete[] works fine in my code but cuda host operation cause error. Is there any situation that may result in this?

Comment: I believe your range-based for is returning a temporary.  Try changing `auto` to `auto&&` in each range-based for

Comment: Isn't this just a scope problem? Trying to call API functions in the destructor of a main scope class when the context has already been destroyed?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, apologize one more time for the sloppy code. I was using a for loop and specified bitmap[i] in the original code. And as stated above, i tried to change to 5 variable but not an array but it didn't work. I added the code in the discription.

Comment: @talonmies, when will the context destroy happen? I think I call free before the context destroyed?

Comment: I give up.  If I offer any more suggestions, you will tell me that this is not the code you are using and change it again.  I'm not very good at hitting moving targets.  I suggest providing a [mcve]  I can only conclude you have not done that.

Comment: Your example as provided works and is functionally correct. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @willkill07 i solved the problem by initialize the pointer to zero at the beginning of for loop. don't how it works but it does. I did not change other part of the code. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score -2):

The problem is solved by first initialize the point to zero before allocate the memory, i.e. add bitmap[i] = 0 at the beginning of the for loop.
Not really sure how this effects the result but it works.

Comment: It's very unlikely that initializing the pointer is the cause of any problem you've had with your code.

Comment: @einpoklum, I know it sounds weird and cannot be explained. However, i did nothing to the pointer anywhere around the code. As stated in the question, I tried to allocate and deallocate the memory in the same function but there are still errors when i free the memory (no error in other parts of the code). If something else is wrong in the code, i think there should be errors in other parts of the code. The error did not occur if i initialize the pointer to zero,  both on GTX970 and 1080 with cuda 7. I am also eager to know why this happens. Thanks.